# Facebook share old content

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, caching, sharing, cache-control

Does anybody know the way to force the cache on facebook?

I mean when we have a lot of pages the `debug facebook tool` started to be a bit usefulness.

The information is changes for example once per week and it's necessary to share a new info via facebook.

Only one idea I have is adding some new `param` to query like `version=1` and increment it each time when content is updated, but I don't like this hardcoded way...

Maybe some `max-age` header or something like this, does anybody experiment on this?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-objects#update // Not sure if that’s a good idea, to regularly change the content while keeping the URL the same. (And if what you’re trying to change includes the title, then you will soon see an error saying “attempted frozen title change” in debug tool – Facebook does not allow you to change the title of an Open Graph object any more, after it has been liked/shared a certain amount of times.) Why not simply use different URLs?

Comment: @CBroe thanks for that details, actually for now the service is actively developing and that's why content is updated, so seems we need to add some extra param then, right?